# Send data to a route using Express JS when you are serving a static file for React-Router

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

**What i'm trying to achieve:** Routes made with Express JS that can fetch data (for example from: https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters), which send it via React Router to my correct route and make React wait until the data is fetched so I can use that data to work with client-side.

**What i've tried**

*server.js*

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'instakbot-client')));

// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'instakbot-client', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.send("I'm just testing to see if this works");
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

*script.js*

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import Router from './routers/';

const init = () => {

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router/>,
        document.querySelector('.react-app')
    );
};

init();
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Frafbot</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<base href="/" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="react-app">
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*app.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>

      <main>
        {children}
      </main>

    </div>
  );
};
```

*routers/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, IndexRedirect, useRouterHistory} from 'react-router';
import {createHistory} from 'history';

import {App, Overview, Users} from '../pages';

export default () => (

  <Router history={useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename: ''})}>

    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRedirect to="home"/>
      <Route path="home" component={Overview} />
      <Route path="users" component={Users} />
    </Route>

  </Router>

);
```

*overview.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>Elaba</h2>
        <div>I am the overview page</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

*users.jsx*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Users extends Component{
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div>
        <p>I am the Users component</p>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Conclusion:** As you can see in server.js I have a get route for '/home', which won't work because there is a get route for '*' to get the static file. But if I put that route ABOVE the '*' route I only get '/home' res... What I want to find is a way to add data by adding a route... You can kind of see it as a route that gets all the default values but can also be overwritten or get additional values...

Is there any possibility I can fetch the data from https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters and get the data in my React component to work with?

Thanks in advance for helping me, I've tried a lot to get this working already...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would declare the routes like:

```js
// Declare API routes before '*'
// Note this route has 'api' prefix
app.get('/api/home', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "I'm just testing to see if this works" });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'instakbot-client', 'index.html'));
});
```

And then on the React client app:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = { message: null }
  componentDidMount() {
     fetch('/api/home') // fetch from Express.js server
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setState({ message: result.message }));
  }

  render() {
    const { message } = this.state;
    // ...
  }
}

export default () => (

  <Router history={useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename: ''})}>

    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="home" component={Overview} />
      <Route path="users" component={Users} />
    </Route>

  </Router>

);
```

Related question: https://github.com/mrpatiwi/routed-react/issues/1

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly, I've been looking for this for days now and I tried this same technique but I didn't name my route "api/home", so the route maybe interfered with that of react-router?... I'm receiving my data right now (which is awesome, thanks once again), but now how can I tell React to wait until the fetch is done so it doesn't get rendered immediately? Or do I want to render for example an empty <ul> and if the content gets updated i let React re-render it? Thanks again, you're a champ.

Comment: You have to differentiate the server-side routes from the client-side routes. In this case you always will have to render before the data get fetched. But take this as something in your favor: you can show loading indicators and make your client-side view more dynamic :)

Comment: PD: You can try server-side rendering to render on the server. But this adds extra complexity to your application.